# How do I select the Last Name element on Microsoft CRM form that has the name <input id = "lastname_i"...> using Python selenium driver?

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, dynamics-crm, element

I have no clue why my CRM driver is not catching this below `HTML` element.  I have tried using absolute and relative XPath, tried using `webdriver.get_element_by_id('lastname_i')`, `get_element_by_css_selector('input.lastname_i')`, and many more scripting possibilities.  For whatever reason, the webdriver does not find this element.

Can anyone help me with the correct Python script?  I think it has something to do with the fact there is no `/>` in the HTML element I am trying to find.

```
<div class="ms-crm-Inline-Edit  ms-crm-Inline-HasError"><input id="lastname_i" attrname="lastname" attrpriv="create, read, update" maxlength="50" title="" class="ms-crm-InlineInput" controlmode="alwaysedit" style="ime-mode: active;" aria-invalid="true" type="text"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait for `20` seconds and try this below code.

```
webdriver.get_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='lastname_i']")
```